# rsync 3.0.9 on source HFS+ destination centos

Tags: centos, rsync, hfs+

My source is an old external hard drive formatted HFS+ (used to be data from server running 10.4.11) connected to an iMac running 10.8.5 with an upgraded version of rsync 3.0.9.

The destination is a Centos 6.4 server running rsync 3.0.9 as well.

We have tried to transfer a FONTS folder (Source size = 4.7GB) to the destination but the size of the folder is not kept (Destination size = 655MB). 
Below is the command that I run to preserve hard links - ACLs.....

/usr/local/bin/rsync -aHpEXotg --devices --specials --ignore-errors /Users/london/Desktop/FONTS root@192.168.200.253:/home/TEST

Also getting errors: rsync: rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr(""/home/TEST/FONTS/ Folder/Kfz-EURO Schrift MAC+PC/MAC/FE Mittelschrift.image"","user.com.apple.FinderInfo") failed: Operation not supported (95)

Most of the files are showing as Unix files and can't be open.
This issue has been time consuming so if someone can guide me.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Ran across this today as I encountered similar errors. I ended up running rsync with minimum options to complete the copy:
    rsync -r --progress /path/to/source /path/to/destination

-r is recursive
--progress shows additional copy info (versus v for verbose output)

If you leave out --progress, rsync will only show you files that error and will transfer the rest - that can be useful to know which files you're not getting if there aren't very many with errors. Course, alternatively if there are a lot of errors, that can indicate bad sectors on the drive.

Comment: Also note, if you're running rsync on a linux box, make sure to install HFS+ filesystem tools. Example for Ubuntu, in terminal: sudo apt-get install hfsprogs

Centos/Redhat: yum install hfsplus (I believe...)